# VueJS - require a javascript file, but ignore formatting errors

Tags: vuejs2

I have a JS file from a purchased theme that I need to `require` in my project, but doing so throws all sorts of formatting errors. The ones like `Strings must use single quotes` and `Trailing spaces not allowed`. Well I didn't write this JS file, and there are formatting errors on almost every line.

Can't I `require` it and force VueJS to ignore the formatting issues?

Comment: It's not Vue.js that is throwing those errors, but rather webpack which is using eslint, you can turn these checks off by using .eslintrc

Comment: @fatman Ah, good to know. Generally, I really like having these warnings as it keeps my code clean. Is it possible to selectively turn it off -- like for just this one file? Or is it an all-or-nothing kind of settings?

Comment: https://evanhahn.com/disable-eslint-for-a-file/

Comment: @fatman Awesome, thanks!